# Python Flask Apache wsgi Not Wrking

Tags: python, flask, mod-wsgi

EDIT-1 - I was having import issues running the app with `mod_wsgi` and the command line, but I have resolved those. I still can't get the `mod_wsgi` part to work, as detailed below.

EDIT-2 Now the `mod_wsgi` is loading the login page, but the sqlite db is complaining. And one import either works for mod_wsgi, or the command line invocation, depending on how it is written.

EDIT-3 Fixed the sqlite error. Needed to have the full path to the db file in the factory. I still have the import issue as described below.

I have a flask application (my first) in a `rocket_launcher_flask/rocket_launcher` and I can't seem to get the both the command line invocation and the wsgi connection to work with the same code base. The errors occur in two places.

In the factory function in `__init__.py` I have this import:

```
#from . import rocket_launcher   # works for command line launch
import rocket_launcher           # works for wsgi
app.register_blueprint(rocket_launcher.bp)
```

If I just use the `import rocket_launcher` and run from the command line, I get this error:

```
  File "/home/mark/python-projects/rocket_launcher_flask/rocket_launcher/__init__.py", line 67, in create_app
    app.register_blueprint(rocket_launcher.bp)
AttributeError: module 'rocket_launcher' has no attribute 'bp'
```

But, if you look at the `rocket_launcher.py` file, `bp` is defined at the top of the file (complete file shown below):

```
from flask import (
    Blueprint, flash, g, redirect, render_template, request, session, url_for, make_response
)
bp = Blueprint('rocket_launcher', __name__)
```

If I run the app using wsgi, the app works as expected.

However, if I change the import to

```
from . import rocket_launcher   # works for command line launch
#import rocket_launcher           # works for wsgi
app.register_blueprint(rocket_launcher.bp)
```

and run from the command line, there are no errors and the app works as designed with no other code changes.

However, running the app using this import and using wsgi yields this error:

```
Sat Dec 03 16:11:59.368196 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 1297960:tid 140355496306432] [client 192.168.25.15:57682]   File "/home/mark/python-projects/rocket_launcher_flask/rocket_launcher/__init__.py", line 65, in create_app, referer: http://192.168.25.15/
[Sat Dec 03 16:11:59.368201 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 1297960:tid 140355496306432] [client 192.168.25.15:57682]     from . import rocket_launcher, referer: http://192.168.25.15/
[Sat Dec 03 16:11:59.368218 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 1297960:tid 140355496306432] [client 192.168.25.15:57682] ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package, referer: http://192.168.25.15/
```

The app uses this invocation for the command line:

```
#!/bin/bash
export FLASK_APP=rocket_launcher
export FLASK_ENV=development
python -m flask run --host=0.0.0.0
```

My application has the following structure:

```
   ├── rocket_launcher_flask
      ├── instance
      ├── run.sh  -- script (above) to run app from CLI
        ├── rocket_launcher.sqlite
      ├── rocket_launcher
        ├── auth.py
        ├── db.py
        ├── fsm.py
        ├── hardware.py
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── model.py
        ├── rocket_launcher_flask.wsgi
        ├── rocket_launcher.py
        ├── schema.sql
        ├── static
        ├── templates
        │   ├── <lots of templates>
```

My new and improved `rocket_launcher_flask.wsgi` file:

```
#! /home/mark/.virtualenvs/rocket_launcher_flask/bin/python

import logging
import sys

logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)

sys.path.insert(0, '/home/mark/python-projects/rocket_launcher_flask/rocket_launcher')
#sys.path.insert(0, '/home/mark/.virtualenvs/rocket_launcher_flask/lib/python3.8/site-packages/')
#sys.path.insert(0, '/home/mark/.virtualenvs/rocket_launcher_flask/bin/python')

activate_this = '/home/mark/.virtualenvs/rocket_launcher_flask/bin/activate_this.py'
with open(activate_this) as file_:
    exec(file_.read(), dict(__file__=activate_this))

logging.error("path=%s" % sys.path)

from __init__ import create_app
application = create_app()
```

My `__init__.py`:

```
import os
from datetime import datetime
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for
from flask_wtf.csrf import CSRFProtect

global launcher

import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/mark/python-projects/rocket_launcher_flask/rocket_launcher')
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/mark/.virtualenvs/rocket_launcher_flask/lib/python3.8/site-packages/')
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/mark/.virtualenvs/rocket_launcher_flask/bin/python')
print("sys.path=%s" % sys.path)

def create_app(test_config=None):
    # create and configure the app
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=False)
    app.config.from_mapping(
        DEBUG=False,
        SECRET_KEY=os.urandom(42),                                         #b'\xc29\xe7\x98@\xc3\x12~\xde3\xed\nP\x1e\x8f\xcd',  #created from python -c 'import os; print(os.urandom(16))'
        DATABASE=os.path.join(app.instance_path, '/full/path/to/rocket_launcher.sqlite'),       
    )
    if 'WINGDB_ACTIVE' in os.environ:
        app.debug = False    
    
    csrf = CSRFProtect()
    csrf.init_app(app)    

    if test_config is None:
        # load the instance config, if it exists, when not testing
        app.config.from_pyfile('config.py', silent=True)
    else:
        # load the test config if passed in
        app.config.from_mapping(test_config)

    # ensure the instance folder exists
    try:
        os.makedirs(app.instance_path)
    except OSError:
        pass
    
    @app.context_processor
    def get_copyright_years():   
        start = '2021'
        now = datetime.utcnow()
        end = str(now.year)
        return {'copyright_years': "%s - %s" % (start, end)}

    # a simple page that says hello
    @app.route('/hello')
    def hello():
        return 'Hello, World!'
    
    from . import db
    db.init_app(app)  
    
    from . import auth
    app.register_blueprint(auth.bp)
    app.add_url_rule('/', endpoint='auth.login')   
    
    #import rocket_launcher       # works for wsgi
    from . import rocket_launcher # works for command line
    app.register_blueprint(rocket_launcher.bp)  

    from . import model
    app.register_blueprint(model.bp) 

    from . import fsm
    app.register_blueprint(fsm.bp)    
    
    return app
```

My rocket_launcher.py - I removed most of the function bodies to keep things easier to read.

```
import functools
from fsm import launcher
import hardware
import logging
from flask import (
    Blueprint, flash, g, redirect, render_template, request, session, url_for, make_response
)
from werkzeug.exceptions import abort
from auth import login_required, logout
from db import get_db

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

bp = Blueprint('rocket_launcher', __name__)

def create_safe_response(endpoint=None, template=None, **data):

@bp.route('/connected', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
@login_required
def connected():

@bp.route('/armed', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
@login_required
#@valid_key_required
def armed():    

@bp.route('/ignition', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
@login_required
#@valid_key_required
#@launch_initiated
def ignition():

@bp.route('/ignition_timer_done', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
@login_required
def ignition_timer_done():
    
@bp.route('/admin', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
@login_required
def admin():

def get_continuity(test=False):
```

Thanks for any suggestions you may have to fix my import problems!

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but whats your `cwd` when you try to run the project? Usually that's the problem with imports in Flask/python apps

Comment: Ideally you should run the flask app from `   ├── rocket_launcher_flask` directory, then you can use `from . import reocket....` statement.

Comment: I added the location of the `run.sh` script to run the app from the command line. It is in the `rocket_launcher_flask` directory, above the rocket_launcher app. The `from . import rocket_launcher` works for the command line invocation, but not for the wsgi invocation. The wsgi file is in the `rocket_launcher` app. Is that the problem??

Comment: Well, that was not it. I moved the wsgi file up to the rocket_launcher_flask directory and that did not change the behavior. I cannot get the app configured to run either from the command line or from wsgi with the same code base. Still have to change that one import statement depending on which way I run the app. Frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is **the** **answer**, but it is a workable solution.

I changed the name of the the file `rocket_launcher.py` to `controller.py` and changed the appropriate references to `rocket_launcher` in the code to `controller`.

I then changed the import in `__init__.py` to `import controller'.

And voila, it works for both wsgi and command line invocations!

I guess there were too many `rocket_launcher` references that pointed to different things, and python got confused?? A much more knowledgeable Pythonista will have to answer that question.